# Setting the screen origin in OpenCV 2.x (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to set the origin of the image I'm getting from my camera in OpenCV and I'm using cv::Mat instead of an IplImage. I know that you can set the origin in an IplImage (img->origin = 0 or 1) but I wasn't able to find any information on how to do the same for a cv::Mat.

1. I want to be able to set the origin to the top left or bottom left of the screen
2. Are there any functions on cv::Mat that lets me do that?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.  According to the API, IplImage has a field for the origin (naturally), but CvMat does not.  This makes sense because there's no concept of an origin with matrices.

FYI here's the API I used: [OpenCV](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-pub/oleykin/website/OpenCVHelp/)

Comment: You can though use http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/operations_on_arrays.html#cv-flip cv::flip to flip an image to effectively put the origin where you

Comment: Good point.  You can also convert the matrix into an image via cvGetImage, set the origin, perform the op, then transform back to a matrix via cvGetMat.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, Martin, doesn't flip flip the image? I think I should convert the Mat into an image and set the origin and convert it back. I wish there was a more efficient way to do it. I will be doing this on each frame in a video for gesture recognition.